# Installing a git-cloned laravel 5.4 project on local machine

Tags: php, mysql, git, laravel-5.4

i tried to install a recently cloned project from github and I keep getting this error on the command line;

> in line container.php,
>   class db does not exist.

I am new to Laravel and I don't find this error friendly. What do I do so I can easily install the project on my local PC without that error?

Comment: Which project is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blaravel%5D+%22class+db+does+not+exist%22

Comment: its a laravel 5.4 web application. This app was uploaded on github for me to pull and run a few changes on the application